# why can not use await getTemporaryDirectory in main in flutter

Tags: flutter, async-await

The code is here. I add getTemporaryDirectory in main.but It make the screen white.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await getTemporaryDirectory();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // new line
  await getTemporaryDirectory();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Read more about the `ensureInitialized` method here : [WidgetsBinding ensureInitialized](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsFlutterBinding/ensureInitialized.html)

Comment: I don't what is the purpose of await getTemporaryDirectory(), because it is not assigned to a variable. It's an unecessary statement.

Comment: Ah yeah I noticed now that he has Future<void> pulling a sneaky.